# Bootstrap modal "hide" not working

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-modal

I tried out about a dozen tips offered on SO to make the modal go away, but none of them solved my problem. First, allow me to share some details surrounding the problem.

The modal is popped up by a user triggered event (i.e., button click), but it is supposed to disappear when a JavaScript timing event comes to an end. See below pseudo code:

```
User event is triggered that sends Ajax requests to server
Show modal
Create JS timing event
Let the timing event wait until all Ajax requests are finished
Hide modal
```

Using IE's DOM Explorer, I observed the state of the modal mark-ups to be as follows (This is after all the Ajax calls are completed):

```
<div class='modal hide in' id='progress-indicator-dialog' aria-hidden='false' style='display:block;' data-keyboards='false' data-backdrop='static'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
        <h1 id='progress-indicator-dialog-title'>Processing...</h1>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
        <div class='progress progress-striped active'>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also noticed in DOM Explorer that a `display: none;` definition for `.hide` style that belongs to the `progress-indicator-dialog` element is somehow overridden. I think that might be the cause.

Anyway, I tried the standard `.modal('hide')` method as well as `.css('display','none')`, `.remove()` and a few other "hacks" but nothing seemed to work.

I'm very much open to ideas/tips.

**EDIT:**

Note - This is part of a customized Orchard (open source CMS) which is based on .NET MVC framework. The reason why I cannot simply copy and paste the entire code is that much of the DOM is generated on the fly and it is huge. I am trying to pick out only the relevant part of the code.

**jQuery:**

```
$("#export-html").click(function () {
    // some initialization
    // ....

    $("#progress-indicator-dialog").modal();
    $("#progress-indicator-dialog-title").text("Processing...");

    $.each(checkedIds, function(i, val) {
        var jqxhr = 
            $.ajax({
                // ...
            });

        jqxhr.then(function () {
            var interval = setInterval( function() { doThis() }, 500};

            function doThis() {
                var el = $("#temp-html").find("div.document-body");
                if (el.length > 0) {
                    stopInterval();
                } else {
                    // ...
                }
            }

            function stopInterval() {
                clearInterval(interval);

                // some action

                iteration++;
            }
        });
    });

    var allDone = setInterval( function() { doThat() }, 500);

    function doThat() {
        if (iteration >= totalNum) {
            clearInterval(allDone);
            $("#progress-indicator-dialog").modal('hide');

            // ...

        }
    }
});
```

**HTML:** (only the modal part)

```
<div class='modal hide' id='progress-indicator-dialog' data-backdrop='static' data-keyboard='false'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
        <h1 id='progress-indicator-dialog-title>...</h1>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
        <div class='progress progress-stripped active'>
            <div class='bar' style='width:100%;'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will be better if you can share an example on jsfiddle or like that

Comment: Show your JavaScript code, please.

Comment: @Danko - I would if it were that simple. I simplified my example in this post, but I'm actually dealing with a CMS package (called Orchard) where some code parts are generated on the fly. Extracting my code piece out of this context would be just too much work.

Comment: `style='display:block;'` on the modal element is the culprit. Since you aren't sharing your code, I don't know from where this is coming.

Comment: @DerekS - I understand that the 'display' value should be 'none' when the process is over. But my question is WHY the .modal('hide') wouldn't work, or any other manual effort to just hide or remove the entire 'div' using jQuery.

Comment: @BinaryCat is the code actually hitting the `.modal('hide')`? I don't see anything obviously wrong in the partial code.

Comment: Does `$("#progress-indicator-dialog").modal('hide');` work if you try it in the browser console?

Comment: You could also try `$('.modal.in').modal('hide')`.

Comment: All - I double checked that the .modal('hide') part gets hit at the end. I tried selecting the modal element using its ID, class, element type, and other ways to no avail. Thanks everyone for the attention.

Comment: can you make an online view so we can see the problem and check the JS? Try to change the css on modal hide with js after your ajax and JS computations.